# How to check when erc20 token was received in certain address

Tags: solidity, ether

i am hosting a node and fully sync it. how i can call its api endpoints to figure out when DGX is received in certain wallet addresses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For communicating with an ethereum e.g. geth, you can call its [json-rpc api](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#json-rpc-api).
For your case the eth_[getLogs](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_getlogs) Function

ERC20 smart Contracts have the "transfer" event. You can query your node for the events of the smart contract address and filter for this log.

```
   /** 
 * @dev Emitted when `value` tokens are moved from one account (`from`) to
 * another (`to`).
 *
 * Note that `value` may be zero.
 */
event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);
```

[Link for openZeppelin IERC20 contract Interface](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol)

Comment: it will give me list of events but i want a last event on particular address.

Comment: The eth_getLogs call provides these filter options: "address" for events originating from the smart contract. When you look in the code example above, you see that "from" and "to" are indexed. Indexed parameters will be accepted into the "topic" field of a log, so you can filter for these too.

Comment: will it give me the time when last token was transfered on this address ?

Comment: Unfortunatly this is limited to the block when the event was created. So you need to make a second lookup for when the block was mined to get an approximation.

Comment: can i use getPastEvents method for same?

Comment: where and how i can call eth_getLogs

Comment: You could use "eth_getBlockByHash" which method returns a unix timestamp.

The json-rpc api link from above describes how to call the json api with curl, also there are many client libraries which can abstract the raw calls for you.
Also the rpc endpoint should be enabled in your node.